# OpenMP while loop inside parallel

Tags: multithreading, openmp

//

EDIT: How do i make 5 threads run code A and the 6th thread run code B CONCURRENTLY then pass their result into a single thread after ALL threads have their code ? I read that im not allowed to use the keyword barrier [OpenMP threads "disobey" omp barrier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771501/openmp-threads-disobey-omp-barrier)

This was my original code

```
omp_set_num_threads(6);
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        int TID = omp_get_thread_num();

        while (true)
        {
            if (TID < 5)
            {
                // codeA

            }

            else
            {
                // codeB
            }

            // combine result from A and B
            #pragma single
            {
                //show result A and B
            }
        }
    }
```

I might have found a solution after googling enough [Can I assign multiple threads to a code section in OpenMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322960/can-i-assign-multiple-threads-to-a-code-section-in-openmp)

I should be able to set 5 threads to do task A and 1 thread to do task B. I just gotta use critical before exiting the 5 threads to accumulate the results.

Comment: Please avoid asking several times the same question. If you want to make [your initial question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36100511/5239503) clearer, just edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following code exemplify what you want to implement? In this particular case, threads 0-4 simply accumulate their thread identifier plus one into `Aresult` (and since it is a shared variable, we need to atomic accesses to it), while thread 5 simply assigns its thread identifier into `Bresult`.
BTW: you missed the omp in `#pragma omp single`.

Notice that I added a couple of `#pragma omp barrier` in between the showing the result for A and B in order to prevent threads altering the values calculated in Aresult/Bresult. This may occur if we don't add the barrier and any thread that does not go through the `#pragma omp single` starts working on the next iteration.

Notice that adding barriers is possible because as the accepted answer in [OpenMP threads "disobey" omp barrier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771501/openmp-threads-disobey-omp-barrier) states

> From OpenMP V3.0/section 2.5 Worksharing Constructs:
>
> The following restrictions apply to worksharing constructs:
>
> Each worksharing region must be encountered by all threads in a team
>   or by none at all. The sequence of worksharing regions and barrier
>   regions encountered must be the same for every thread in a team.

and in this case, every thread encounters the barrier before and after entering the code that shows the results.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int Aresult = 0;
    int Bresult = 0;

    omp_set_num_threads(6);
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int TID = omp_get_thread_num();

        while (1 == 1)
        {
            if (TID < 5)
            {
                // codeA
                #pragma omp atomic
                Aresult += TID + 1; // Aresult should be 1+2+3+4+5
            }
            else
            {
                // codeB
                Bresult = TID;
            }

            #pragma omp barrier

            // combine result from A and B
            #pragma omp single
            {
                //show result A and B
                printf ("Aresult = %d Bresult = %d\n", Aresult, Bresult);

                // set Aresult & Bresult to 0 for next iteration
                Aresult = Bresult = 0;
            }

            #pragma omp barrier
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the second barrier is unnecessary, as the `single` construct already has an implicit barrier at its end. [Here](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu38.html) is the documentation of `single`. Otherwise, you could also add a `nowait` clause to remove the implicit barrier in `single`.